# In Rust, how do I use implemented trait FromStr on BigInt?

Tags: rust

I am trying to get this program to compile:

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;
use std::from_str::FromStr;

fn main () {
    println!("{}", BigInt::from_str("1"));
}
```

But the output from `rustc` is

```
testing.rs:6:20: 6:36 error: unresolved name `BigInt::from_str`.
testing.rs:6     println!("{}", BigInt::from_str("1"));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:23: 2:77 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:2 note: in expansion of println!
testing.rs:6:5: 6:43 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I suspect I am doing something trivially wrong, but I've tried searching for examples and tried a bunch of different changes and nothing I tried worked.

How do I change my source code so this compiles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plain function `from_str` has been removed in recent versions of Rust. This function is now only available as a method of the `FromStr` trait.

The modern way to parse values is the [`.parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) method of `str`:

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;

fn main() {
    match "1".parse::<BigInt>() {
        Ok(n)  => println!("{}", n),
        Err(_) => println!("Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;

fn main () {
    println!("{}", from_str::<BigInt>("1"));
}
```

In function calls, you need to put `::` before the angle brackets.

Comment: Thank you. Using that helper function seems nice and idiomatic. I'm curious how to make the direct call to the implementation work.

Comment: Something like `BigInt::from_str` isn't possible.

Comment: with rust beta it's [parse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse) `"1".parse::<BigInt>()`  

or for calling from_str directly
`let test2 : Result<BigNum, _> = FromStr::from_str("123");`

Answer (score 1):

This works for calling the trait implementation directly instead of through the utility function. **This is not idiomatic.**

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;
use std::from_str::FromStr;

fn main () {
    let x : Result<BigInt,_> = FromStr::from_str("1");
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Comment: The prelude contains a function `from_str` that avoids the need to use `std::from_str::FromStr`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMorgan I edited the answer to be more sure that this is not idiomatic.

Comment: Readers from the future: it's now called `std::str::FromStr`.

Comment: with rust beta it's `let x : Result<BigInt,_> = FromStr::from_str("1");`

Answer (score 1):

Your original code works almost as-is:

```
use num::bigint::BigInt; // 0.2.0
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", BigInt::from_str("1"));
}
```

You need to switch to `std::str::FromStr` and `from_str` returns a `Result` which requires the `{:?}` (`Debug`) formatter.