# Unresolved import from_str

Tags: rust

How do I use `from_str` ? I have the snippet

```
let base: u32 = from_str::<u32>(&var)
```

and get the error

```
Error: unresolved name from_str
```

So I googled this error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391440/in-rust-how-do-i-use-implemented-trait-fromstr-on-bigint), so I tried adding the following

```
use std::u32;
use std::from_str::FromStr
```

But now I get

```
Error: unresolved import `std::from_str::FromStr` could not from `from_str` in `std`
```

According to [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20525) github issue, I need to include this yet rust can't find it. What's going on? Here's a **super** simple program which gives me those errors

```
use std::u32;
use std::from_str::FromStr;

fn main() {

    let my_str = "String".to_string();
    let base: u32 = from_str(&my_str);
}
```

This is such a trivial issue and yet these resources are only showing me how to get more errors.

Answer (score 9):

[Use the docs to search for `from_str`.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=from_str) They show that the `FromStr` trait is in `std::str` now, not `std::from_str`. (April 2014 is a *long* time ago in Rust terms, being well before Rust 1.0.0.)

`FromStr` should not be used directly in general anyway; you should use [`str.parse` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) instead: `my_str.parse::<u32>()`. Remember that it returns a `Result`, because the string might just not contain a number.