# How to parse BigInt from the num crate?

Tags: rust, bigint

I am trying to use [`BigInt`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/bigint/struct.BigInt.html). My code is like this:

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;
...
println!("{}", from_str::<BigInt>("1")); //this is line 91 in the code
```

In my Cargo.toml file I have the following:

```
[dependencies]
num = "0.1.30"
```

What I did seem to match what was said in [this document](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/bigint/struct.BigInt.html#method.from_bytes_be), [also this document](http://docs.piston.rs/conrod/num/bigint/struct.BigInt.html) and also [an answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391440/in-rust-how-do-i-use-implemented-trait-fromstr-on-bigint).

However I got the following error:

```
Compiling example v0.1.0 (file:///C:/src/rust/example)
src\main.rs:91:20: 91:38 error: unresolved name `from_str` [E0425]
src\main.rs:91     println!("{}", from_str::<BigInt>("1"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out, seem like the current syntax is:

```
"8705702225074732811211966512111".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();
```

Better yet, do the following:

```
match "8705702225074732811211966512111".parse::<BigInt>() {
    Ok(big) => {
        ...
```

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear: all the examples that use `from_str` are out of date, this function has been removed in favour of `.parse`.